# Bukkit custom inventory not updating

Tags: bukkit

I'm trying to change the item a slot in a custom inventory contains based on the item that is in another slot in the same inventory. Here's the code I have now:

```
@EventHandler
public void processInventoryEvent(InventoryClickEvent e) {
  if (e.getRawSlot() == 11) {
    if (e.getCursor().getType() == Material.COAL || e.getCursor().getType() == Material.LOG || e.getCursor().getType() == Material.LOG_2) {
      e.getInventory.setItem(10, new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, DyeColor.GREEN.getData());
    } else {
      e.getInventory.setItem(10, new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, DyeColor.RED.getData());
    }
  }
}
```

The current problem is that the inventory doesn't seem to be updating, so the inventory needs to be reopened to see the change, and I want the item to change when the player places an item in that slot.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think we'll need some more info on your plugin to help you. I tried to recreate your issue, but since I don't know what kind of custom inventory you are using I used the default player inventory, in which case the glass pane/invalid fuel item immediately updated. What kind of an item is `GrillIconStates.FUEL_INVALID.item`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to edit that to what it is. I have an enumeration of items, and that's just a red glass pane. Also, I'm using a `Bukkit.createInventory()` inventory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently updating the player's inventory also updates any other open inventories. Got it working properly with this block after the conditionals:

```
plugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    for (HumanEntity he : e.getInventory().getViewers()) {
      Player p = (Player) he;
      p.updateInventory();
    }
  }
}, 1L);
```

The one tick delay is needed, otherwise derpiness ensues (items don't go where you click them straightaway).